# how to create custom directories with custom names

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create profiles folders, but I don't know how to create or move in other directory. I think that it could be done using `system("...");` like in `CMD`, but I cannot get it to work to create a custom directory name.

I want to do this:

- create a folder with a custom name (say, a username)
- create a file in that directory, and name it like the directory's name
- the possibility to rename or delete the file or folder

I don't know if leaving the principal directory (where the main `.cpp` file is) is going to affect my program in some way.

Comment: If you have a modern compiler that supports the 2017 standard start reading this: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Comment: ***i don't know if leaving the principal directory (where the main cpp file is) is going to affect in someway my program*** It's not. These are totally independent.

Comment: IMHO, naming files the same name as the directory is evil.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a modern compiler that supports the cxx17 standard you can read this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

here a small example of what you want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main(){
// create a dir 
  fs::path path_dir = "/path/you/want"
  fs::create_directories(path_dir);

//create a file
   fs::path file_path = path_dir / "my_new_file.txt"; 
    std::ofstream ofs(file_path.string());
    ofs << "this is some text in the new file\n"; 
    ofs.close();

//remove file 
  fs::remove(file_path);

//remove dir and file if exist
  fs::remove_all(path_dir)

  return 0;
}
```